# name 'HTML' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am working with the `Django` project and trying to render a pdf with `WeasyPrint`.

my `views.py`:

```
def WeasyPDF(request):
    paragraphs = ['first paragraph', 'second paragraph', 'third paragraph']
    html_string = render_to_string('app/pdf_report.html', {'paragraphs': paragraphs})

    html = HTML(string=html_string)
    html.write_pdf(
    target='/tmp/mypdf.pdf',
    stylesheets=[
        # Change this to suit your css path
        settings.BASE_DIR + 'css/bootstrap.min.css',
        settings.BASE_DIR + 'css/main.css',
    ],
    );

    fs = FileSystemStorage('/tmp')
    with fs.open('mypdf.pdf') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
        return response
    return response
```

But it says the following error:

```
name 'HTML' is not defined
```

I was following this tutorial: [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/08/how-to-export-to-pdf.html).

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: Have you imported such a name?

Comment: No, I haven't imported that type of thing.

Comment: Then it's little wonder it's not defined...

Comment: `from weasyprint import HTML` from [WeasyPrint docs](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html). Also looks like they have a library for Django: [django-weasyprint](https://github.com/fdemmer/django-weasyprint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have skipped the import part of the code in the tutorial which should be right on top of your `WeasyPDF` function:

```py
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from weasyprint import HTML

def WeasyPDF(request):
```

In addition, I recommend not to use `PascalCase` style of naming functions - in python it is inconvinient and may mislead someone you are defining a class, not a function. [Read PEP8 for more information](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).